# link to a single article with catatogy

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, category

I am new to `Joomla`. I have created a module that shows some articles with a link to those articles.

I fetched latest articals with :

```
<?php $list= ModArticlesLatestHelper::getList($params);
   foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url"></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

i get a url that is in the form

```
`www.example.com/{articleID}-{article-name}`
```

Please tell me how can i get a URL in the following form.

`www.example.com/{catagoryID}-{catagory-name}/{articleID}-{article-name}`

Comment: Please post your code of how you formed `$item->link`.

Comment: @Nagarjun I have edited my question, Please let me know if i need to provide any more details. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your article urls are managed using menu items. To get the correct menu structure, create one `Category List` or `Category Blog` menu item for each of the "Top Level" category. This way, your article urls will look like this:

```
/{categorymenualias}/{id}-{article-alias}
```

Or the articles in subcategories:

```
/{categorymenualias}/{catid}-{subcategory}/{id}-{article-alias}
```

Now in your module helper class, you can build your article urls using Content component helper.

```
$item->link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->id,  $item->catid ));
```

You may need to include the helper in your module.

```
require_once(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');
```

Note: Your menu items can be under a Menus which you need not show on front-end using Menu module.